# Linking Files In Html

Tags: html

so i'm fairly new to html, so i have always just left everything in the same folder so i don't have to link things but am making a professional website for myself and portfolio. so i want to sort my files properly.

so lets say i have a folder called website, then in that folder i have 3 folders, html, css and images. my html documents are in the html folder what do i do to link images from the images folder in the html document that is in the html folder. pleas note that images isn't a sub folder of html they are both sub folders of website.

any help is helpful (self explanatory i know)

Comment: You are looking for `relative paths`

Answer (score 0):

If the html folder and images folder are siblings, the path from a file in the html folder to an asset in the images folder would look like this:

"../images/mypic.jpg"

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in the html page by adding the img tag:

```
<img src="../images/yourImage.png" alt="" />
```

But the better method would be to use CSS:

```
<img alt="" />

img {
    background-image: url("../images/yourImage.png");
}
```

Notice that the "../" is used to go up one level from the current directory of your html page or css file.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply prepend your urls with `/` which will always reference the root folder of your website.

Assuming `yoursite.com` loads the folder contents of `website`, you can link to files in the images directory like this:

`/images/image.jpg` which will produce `http://yoursite.com/images/image.jpg`

**Example:**
`<img src="/images/image.jpg" />`

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways that the links could work whether from the root:

```
<a href="http://www.yourdomain.com/images/image.jpg">
```

Or perhaps once you get a little more experienced with managing your folders, you can set them up a little more dynamic (making them automatically work on live/development transfers):

```
<a href="images/image.jpg">
```

Does that help?

PS: The html or public_html folder is typically your root with a host, meaning you don't need to includ this in your paths. Consider whereever your functional index file is the root folder.

Answer (score 0):

U can use .. to go to previous folder.In your case while pointing path for images in html file you can do as metioned below.

Answer (score 0):

If the image is within the same folder then just use:

```
<img src="image.jpg">
```

If the image is within a sub folder then just use:

```
<img src="subfolder/image.jpg">
```

If the image is within a parent folder then just use:

```
<img src="../otherfolder/image.jpg">
```

or if it is just located in the parent folder

```
<img src="../image.jpg">
```

This is going to explain it in detail:
http://www.htmlkit.com/minit/pages/imgtag1.html